# How to set value for Ansible variable upon when condition in with_itema loop

Tags: loops, variables, if-statement, ansible, conditional-statements

I have a 'with_item' loop in which variable 'USER' needs to be assigned a value based on condition check.

If '{{ command_result.stdout_lines }}' is "Frontend" then USER variable should get value 'user1' else it should be assigned value 'user2'

Below is something I could achieve after seeking help but the problem is that 'USER' always gets assigned 'user2' value even if the condition is met for 'user1'

My playbook:

```
  - debug:
       msg: "User was {{ item.split('\t')[3] }}"
     with_items: "{{ command_result.stdout_lines }}"

   - set_fact:
        USER:  "user1"
     when: item.split('\t')[3] == "FrontEnd"
     with_items: "{{ command_result.stdout_lines }}"

   - set_fact:
        USER:  "user2"
     when: item.split('\t')[3] == "BackEnd"
     with_items: "{{ command_result.stdout_lines }}"

   - debug:
          msg: "User has {{ USER }}"
     with_items: "{{ command_result.stdout_lines }}"
```

The First debug prints and confirms that the value of 
 item.split('\t')[3]

The second debug prints 'USER' but as you can see in the output below it has value 'user2' even when the value is Frontend.

Can you please suggest?

> TASK [debug]
>   ************************************************************************************************************************************************ ok: [localhost] => (item=10.12.1.13     10.12.1.13\n-rw-rw-r-- user1
>   2019-09-13 15:39 /was//testingjsp/testingcom.jsp 1786385840 
>   /was//testingjsp   FrontEnd) => {
>       "msg": "User was FrontEnd" } ok: [localhost] => (item=10.12.1.13     10.12.1.13\n-rw-rw-r-- user2 2019-09-13 15:29 /fin/scripts/testingscr.scr 367595418\n-rw-rw-r-- user2 2019-09-13
>   15:36 /fin/mrt/testingmrt.mrt 1251350031\n-rw-rw-r-- user2 2019-09-13
>   15:37 /fin/exe/testingexe.exe 1390265645\n-rw-rw-r-- user2 2019-09-13
>   15:38 /fin/com/testingcom.com 90193476
>   /fin/scripts\n/fin/mrt\n/fin/exe\n/fin/com   BackEnd) => {
>       "msg": "User was BackEnd" }
>
> TASK [debug]
>   ************************************************************************************************************************************************ ok: [localhost] => (item=10.12.1.13     10.12.1.13\n-rw-rw-r-- user1
>   2019-09-13 15:39 /was//testingjsp/testingcom.jsp 1786385840 
>   /was//testingjsp   FrontEnd) => {
>       "msg": "User has user2" } ok: [localhost] => (item=10.12.1.13     10.12.1.13\n-rw-rw-r-- user2 2019-09-13 15:29 /fin/scripts/testingscr.scr 367595418\n-rw-rw-r-- user2 2019-09-13
>   15:36 /fin/mrt/testingmrt.mrt 1251350031\n-rw-rw-r-- user2 2019-09-13
>   15:37 /fin/exe/testingexe.exe 1390265645\n-rw-rw-r-- user2 2019-09-13
>   15:38 /fin/com/testingcom.com 90193476
>   /fin/scripts\n/fin/mrt\n/fin/exe\n/fin/com   BackEnd) => {
>       "msg": "User has user2" }

Comment: You have 3 items in `command_result.stdout_lines`, and the last is having `BackEnd` as the value of `item.split('\t')[3]`. Hence, the final value present in the fact `USER` is `user2`. So, the playbook is working absolutely fine. Please add what is your end goal?

Comment: I want to print the value of USER in each iteration of the loop so I wish to see user1 and user2 both printed in the loop depending on the matching conditions. The value of user will eventually be supplied to add_host module of Ansible.

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: Also we have 4 items in command_result.stdout_lines and item.split('\t')[3] refers to the 4th item which is FrontEnd in the first iteration and BackEnd in the second i.e last iteration of the loop.

Comment: Okay. First of all, it will work for `n items`. And I can assign an empty string in case it doesn't match any case, then you can filter out the entries in which `USER: ''` while using the values in subsequent tasks.

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: I will be able to check this in the next 12 hrs and update this post. Thank you for the inputs @shubham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the tasks which will get you `USER` for each item in the `command_result`.

```
- set_fact:
    USER:  "{% if item.split('\t')[2] == 'FrontEnd' %}user1{% elif item.split('\t')[2] == 'BackEnd' %}user2{% else %}{% endif %}"
  with_items: "{{ command_result.stdout_lines }}"
  register: "facts"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.ansible_facts.USER }}"
  with_items: "{{ facts.results }}"
```

The first task sets the value of `USER` fact based on the value extracted by `item.split('\t')[3]` and uses jinja2 templating to set the value of `USER`.

If there are `n items` in your `command_result`, the first task will be registering the `USER` fact `n times`. Hence, I have registered the value in `facts` named variable.

The values are accessed and printed in the second task.

You can similarly use the values as shown in the second task in subsequent tasks.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tested this and it works fine. However, I m facing challenges passing each 'USER' to a include_tasks file that builds add_host group.

Comment: @Ashar, the variables registered in a task can be used using `hostvars['host_on_which_the_task_was_executed']['facts']` in another playbook